# How to associate name and publish it to the store, a WinUI3 app?

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am developing a WinUI3 app with Windows App SDK. However, I am unable to find the option to associate its name with the store and publish it to the store in the right-click menu of the project. Am I missing anything in my VS?  (in UWP, there was a submenu named 'Project' which had all these menus).

[image]

This is the Project type I chose.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the "Publish..." context menu entry? The settings for publishing can be done also by doubleclicking on the app.manifest file which will bring up the editor for this file.

Comment: @Martin yes, it just creates an exe with support files like the conventional winforms projects do. It is not the appx bundle file. Nor it shows any page to edit store info like app name, logo, certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Package and Publish]

Please, check "Package and Publish"

I get this menu in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.0.4).
Package for WinUI 3 does not create bundle even though you select it. It will create .msix file, you can upload .msix file to store. If you want to create bundle, you need to create manually using MakeAppx.exe.

Comment: Thank you. I got this menu after updating to 17.0.5